# Why doesn't OnProgressUpdate in an AsyncTask get called?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-asynctask

Using Xamarin.Android, however, I don't think it's the reason behind my issue.

The problem I am facing is that the OnProgressUpdate method only gets called once in an AsyncTask object I'm using handle a background task. Here is my class:

```
public class DBInflater : AsyncTask
{
    private int progress;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public DatabaseInflater(ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        base.OnPreExecute();
    }

    protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run([some heavy task]);

        while (progress < 100)
        {
            Java.Lang.Thread.Sleep(500);
            PublishProgress(progress);
            progress += 1;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params Java.Lang.Object[] values)
    {
        progressBar.Progress = progress;
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        base.OnPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

I've managed to narrow down the problem to this line: Java.Lang.Thread.Sleep(500);
If I use a smaller value for the sleep, the OnProgressUpdate won't get called after the first time. I landed on 500 because with this value, OnProgressUpdate gets called properly and the progressBar updates on the screen.

Is there a reason why I have to sleep the Thread at a certain interval? I'd like the progressBar to update in real time, not every half second.

Comment: 1. Your progress is a _lie_. 2. "If I use a smaller value for the sleep, the OnProgressUpdate won't get called after the first time." - how do determine that?

Comment: in other words `[some heavy task]` should `PublishProgress` into the `doInBackground` thread.

Comment: I should clarify that the [some heavy task] is a Task that I am calling from a shared library. However, I don't believe this is the heart of the issue. The while loop is what's causing me grief. What I left out of my code example were some Log outputs reporting the incoming values[0] value. If I Thread.Sleep(<500), the OnProgressUpdate gets called once (the first time I called PublishProgress). The next time OnProgressUpdate gets called is once DoInBackground is complete - in other words, progress == 100. When I set the Thread.Sleep to 500 or greater, OnProgressUpdate gets called everytime.

Answer (score 3):

Running something in `Task` thread within `DoInBackground` method that does not report its progress does not make any sense.

When `DoInBackground` is called you are not on the UI thread but a background thread, you can check via checking the value of `Looper.MainLooper.IsCurrentThread`, so using `Task.Run` is not necessary.

So once in `DoInBackground` your `DB Inflater` will assumably do a series of steps, creating the DB, creating tables, indexes, etc.. then loading each of the tables with data, etc... It is up to you to determine the amount of progress that has happened and publish it (`PublishProgress`).

In this example, I have three steps and report a 33% increase in the competition after completing each step.

```
public class DBInflaterAsyncTask : AsyncTask
{
    protected override Object DoInBackground(params Object[] @params)
    {
        // You are not on the UI thread

        Task.Delay(1000); // create db
        PublishProgress(new Object[] { 33 });
        Task.Delay(1000); // create tables
        PublishProgress(new Object[] { 66 });
        Task.Delay(1000); // load table data
        PublishProgress(new Object[] { 99 });
        return null;
    }

    protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params Object[] values)
    {
        // You are on the UI thread

        Log.Debug("SomeTag", values[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is probably the best representation of the correct approach, when you don't have an tangible integer value to use as a progress benchmark. So setting your own points of progress is the best option.

Comment: Please refer to the comment I made up above under my question. My issue isn't what's being processed in the background, or what is doing the actual progress calculations. It seems to be the rate at which I am calling PublishProgress.

Comment: @hellaandrew Calling `OnProgressUpdate` places you back on the UI thread, and updating the progress position posts this to the messaging queue, etc... If you are posting events faster then the UI thread can keep up you will get a "long operation" issue (you can enable the visual long operation flash in the dev options on the phone). If you log the `OnProgressUpdate` calls, there is no way they will not be called unless your AsyncTask to throwing an exception & terminating or you are blocking/locking the background thread.

Comment: @hellaandrew  FYI: Arbitrarily updating the progress bar over 50 secs while another thread is doing some processing does not convey much to the user nor does it actually show you if that task is done processing, you might as well set the style to indeterminate and `await` a `Task` result